# Have anybody used System.setPassword method on force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, login-errors

We have a force.com site and we want to build a custom change password feature where users can change their password based on answering a security question. I found that site.changepassword method will only work if the user is logged in only and will not work for unauthenticated users even if we have the user enter a userid on a vf page. So i am trying to use System.setPassword method but it throws a permission error on the force.com site. Do you guys know what i need to do on the site settings to execute system methods on a force.com site?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: Have you tried with `Site.forgotPassword(username)` ?

Comment: buyan, it's unclear from timestamps whether you asked this before or after your blog post — if it was before then I apologise for making issue of it, but if it was after then doing so is really in spirit of the site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a wild guess that maybe you solved your own problem, and posted it on your own website? :)  Either that, or another guy name Buyan found the answer.

For anybody who stumbles on this, you'll probably find this helpful: http://betterapexprogramming.com/creating-a-custom-change-password-page-using-force-com-sites-and-solving-issues-with-dreaded-site-login-and-change-password/